# Enable Schedule Trigger in Azure Data factory through poweshell script

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

I am enabling schedule trigger in data factory through powershell script in release pipeline of Azure DevOps.

I have written script as below:

$triggersADF | ForEach-Object { Start-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName  -DataFactoryName  -Name $_.name -Force }

But I am getting below error.
The term 'Start-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
PowerShell exited with code '1'

How it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install/update latest AzureRM.DataFactoryV2 module. And then
Restart your powershell.

Comment: thankyou after installing and updating the latest AzureRM.DataFactoryV2 module it worked.